# When hiding one fullscreen form and showing another fulscreen one there is unwanted flickering

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2013, flicker

I use this simple lines...:

```
 Char_Creation_1 game = new Char_Creation_1(); 
        game.Show(); 
        this.Hide();
```

...to change forms in our project group's text game. What it does however, is that for the while when changing the forms, it shows the desktop or whatever other window is below the forms at the time (thus flickering). Both forms are meant to be maximized and working without task bar shown and all other windows visible, only the game ones. How do I remove this flickering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, When it closes it shows homescreen immediately it opens a forms so he flicker will happen. Better you can use Mdi forms to avoid flicker and professional look

set your form's

> formborderstyle = None

and

pass your form as parameter

```
CreateMdiChild(new game());
```

also set main form as

> IsMdiContainer = true

```
    public void CreateMdiChild(Form child)
    {
        if (this.ActiveMdiChild != null)
        {
            this.ActiveMdiChild.Close();
        }
        child.MdiParent = this;
        child.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        child.Show();

    }
```